# How to configure an Instance_1 in Region_1 to be able to use a custom VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-lightsail, aws-vpc-peering

I have lightsail instances in multiple regions.

I want to allow Instance_1 in Region_1 to be able to communicate with a custom aws vpc from that region.

I understand that each lightsail instance is an independent vps (virtual private server).

1. Is it correct to say that- when vpc peering is enabled (under account settings), then all the lightsail instances in the region get access to the default vpc of the region?
2. Is there any way to enable it only for 1 lightsail instance?
3. Assuming a region has multiple vpc's (say a default vpc and an additional vpc), then is there any way to enable vpc peering to the non default aws vpc?

Answer (score 2):

No.

VPC Peering in Amazon Lightsail only permits connection to the **Default VPC** in a Region.

It also looks like *all* resources would be included in the peering relationship.

If you need better control, you would need to use Amazon EC2 instead of Amazon Lightsail.

(I suspect that these limitations are intentional, to encourage people with more requirements to use Amazon EC2. Amazon Lightsail is marketed as a 'starter' product with a lower price and therefore less functionality.)

Comment: Does enabling vpc peering allow light sail instances to talk with each other? By default I know that each instance is a vps.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Lightsail instances in the same region can communicate with each other by default. Just think of them as special-case EC2 instances in their own VPC.

Comment: Isn't each lightsail instance a vps (virtual private server) with no connection to other lightsail instances? If not, then why is it called vps virtual private server. I didn't find documentation mentioning that they share the same vpc.

Comment: @variable all Lightsail and EC2 instances can be considered Virtual Private Servers. Those servers have to run in a network, which is what the VPC (Virtual Private Cloud) is. I'm not sure why you think the fact that they could be called VPS implies that they can't talk to each other.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know all of them inherently share the same vpc. I guess this is a default setting and cannot be changed?

Comment: "[VPS](https://www.dreamhost.com/blog/beginners-guide-vps/)" is the generic IT term for a private server in a data center. When people look for a company to host their WordPress site or similar small system, companies try to rent them a Virtual Private Server. Amazon EC2 is a bit different in that it provides complete networking capabilities (VPCs) in addition to virtual computers. When AWS decided to approach the 'smaller end' of the market, they created Amazon Lightsail. While the machines are effectively EC2 instances, Lightsail calls them a VPS to be compatible with the target market.